# get the value sent by ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have:

```
  <form method="POST" name="f">
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload" />
  </form>
```

I'm sent the file using ajax,using the uplaod.file method:

```
document.getElementById('FileUpload').onchange = function() {

        file = this.files[0];
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest; 
        ajax.file = file; 

        //etc.. 


         ajax.open('post','Default.aspx', true);
         ajax.setRequestHeader('foo','baa');

         ajax.send(file);
```

}

```
Request.Forms["FileUplaod"] // don't works
```

How I get the value (the file) sent by ajax in my asp.net application?
I tried sent by http headers(is not pratice good,I know) but there problem with long length.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are spelling Upload wrong...  Request.Forms["FileUplaod"]  Should be Request.Forms["FileUpload"]

Comment: Also spelling `Element` wrong in `document.getElmenetById`

Comment: actually,this codes is examples only..

Answer (score 0):

try this form attribute :

form action="some/action" method="POST" **enctype="multipart/form-data"**